# 'If' statement to change function

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to add an If statement to change the parameters of the a function for one specific point, however the code seems to apply the first function to all points, regardless of the if statement.

The code below creates a new marker, and then performs the function depending on the if statement - at least it should!

What am I doing wrong?

```
function createMarker(point, name, file_name) {

var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
            blueIcon.image = "images/mark22.png";
            blueIcon.iconSize = new GSize(32, 32);

            markerOptions = { icon: blueIcon };
            var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);


GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

    if (marker.name = 'chester') {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<a class='text1' href='http://www.merseyrail.org/plan-your-journey/stations/" + file_name + ".aspx' target='_parent'>" + name + " Station</a><br /><font size='2' face='Arial'><i>Click the station name to view more information.</i></font>");
                }

else {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<img src='images/merseyraillogosmall.png'/><br /><a class='text1' href='http://www.merseyrail.org/plan-your-journey/stations/" + file_name + ".aspx' target='_parent'>" + name + " Station</a><br /><font size='2' face='Arial'><i>Click the station name to view more information.</i></font>");
                }
            });

return marker;
        }
```

and then further down:

```
var point20 = new GLatLng(53.1968, -2.88018);
        map.addOverlay(createMarker(point20, 'Chester'));
```

Comment: Just try `if(marker.name == 'chester')` :)

Comment: Are you ever actually setting the name property of marker (marker.name = name) ?

Comment: @Andre No I hadn't, works perfectly now, thank you! Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be

```
if (marker.name == 'chester')
```

Not

```
if (marker.name = 'chester')
```

Comment: Or even `===`, to be really strict

Comment: And in addition to Deepu's answer, it is case sensitive so if you create "Chester" this will still not work because you compare to "chester" ;)

Comment: Sort of works, but it now bypasses the 'if' statement, applying the 'else' statement to all including Chester - I've changed it to: if (! marker.name == 'chester'), but still nothing.